# Getting black spots in blender render, render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, artifacts

I'm using Blender 2.79. I've looked at a number of possible answers on this, but none seem to help solve the problem. I'm getting these weird black specs in renders when using blender render. I've checked for Z-fighting or duplicate geometry but there is none. These are extremely simple, low poly models that have been duplicated and only use one basic color as it's material. There are only two unique models here, and the rest are just simple rotated duplicates of each-other.

[image: Problem]

I have been able to get the issue be less noticeable by changing world -> gather: from raytrace to approximate. However I would like to know what's going on so that I can keep the setting on raytrace. As you can see below the same two trees have an odd speckled look to it, which doesn't make sense because there is just a basic color as it's material/texture. This does not show up using cycles render. (Again, I do want to use blender render, so looking for a fix)

[image: no raytrace]

Comment: Are you sure, you don't accidently copy these objects and hide them from viewport?

Comment: Wow, yes that was exactly it. I feel like an idiot! Thanks!